# display warning about opcache,curl and many more

Tags: linux-mint, php, shared-library

I am facing problem while run any command. For example i run command `php -v`
and it gives following output.

```
ronak@ronak-pc ~ $ php -v
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: ext/opcache.so (ext/opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/opcache.so.so (ext/opcache.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: ext/curl (ext/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/curl.so (ext/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: ext/intl (ext/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/intl.so (ext/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap' (tried: ext/imap (ext/imap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/imap.so (ext/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: ext/mbstring (ext/mbstring: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mbstring.so (ext/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: ext/mysqli (ext/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mysqli.so (ext/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: ext/openssl (ext/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/openssl.so (ext/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: ext/pdo_mysql (ext/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo_mysql.so (ext/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'soap' (tried: ext/soap (ext/soap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/soap.so (ext/soap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: ext/xsl (ext/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xsl.so (ext/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd.so' (tried: ext/mysqlnd.so (ext/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mysqlnd.so.so (ext/mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo.so' (tried: ext/pdo.so (ext/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo.so.so (ext/pdo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xml.so' (tried: ext/xml.so (ext/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xml.so.so (ext/xml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bcmath.so' (tried: ext/bcmath.so (ext/bcmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/bcmath.so.so (ext/bcmath.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2.so' (tried: ext/bz2.so (ext/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/bz2.so.so (ext/bz2.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'calendar.so' (tried: ext/calendar.so (ext/calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/calendar.so.so (ext/calendar.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ctype.so' (tried: ext/ctype.so (ext/ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/ctype.so.so (ext/ctype.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so' (tried: ext/curl.so (ext/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/curl.so.so (ext/curl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dba.so' (tried: ext/dba.so (ext/dba.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/dba.so.so (ext/dba.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dom.so' (tried: ext/dom.so (ext/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/dom.so.so (ext/dom.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'enchant.so' (tried: ext/enchant.so (ext/enchant.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/enchant.so.so (ext/enchant.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif.so' (tried: ext/exif.so (ext/exif.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/exif.so.so (ext/exif.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo.so' (tried: ext/fileinfo.so (ext/fileinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/fileinfo.so.so (ext/fileinfo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ftp.so' (tried: ext/ftp.so (ext/ftp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/ftp.so.so (ext/ftp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: ext/gd.so (ext/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/gd.so.so (ext/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext.so' (tried: ext/gettext.so (ext/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/gettext.so.so (ext/gettext.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gmp.so' (tried: ext/gmp.so (ext/gmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/gmp.so.so (ext/gmp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'iconv.so' (tried: ext/iconv.so (ext/iconv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/iconv.so.so (ext/iconv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'igbinary.so' (tried: ext/igbinary.so (ext/igbinary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/igbinary.so.so (ext/igbinary.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: ext/imagick.so (ext/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/imagick.so.so (ext/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap.so' (tried: ext/imap.so (ext/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/imap.so.so (ext/imap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase.so' (tried: ext/interbase.so (ext/interbase.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/interbase.so.so (ext/interbase.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so' (tried: ext/intl.so (ext/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/intl.so.so (ext/intl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'json.so' (tried: ext/json.so (ext/json.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/json.so.so (ext/json.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ldap.so' (tried: ext/ldap.so (ext/ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/ldap.so.so (ext/ldap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: ext/mbstring.so (ext/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mbstring.so.so (ext/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'msgpack.so' (tried: ext/msgpack.so (ext/msgpack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/msgpack.so.so (ext/msgpack.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: ext/mysqli.so (ext/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mysqli.so.so (ext/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'odbc.so' (tried: ext/odbc.so (ext/odbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/odbc.so.so (ext/odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_dblib.so' (tried: ext/pdo_dblib.so (ext/pdo_dblib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo_dblib.so.so (ext/pdo_dblib.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird.so' (tried: ext/pdo_firebird.so (ext/pdo_firebird.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo_firebird.so.so (ext/pdo_firebird.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: ext/pdo_mysql.so (ext/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo_mysql.so.so (ext/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc.so' (tried: ext/pdo_odbc.so (ext/pdo_odbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo_odbc.so.so (ext/pdo_odbc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql.so' (tried: ext/pdo_pgsql.so (ext/pdo_pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo_pgsql.so.so (ext/pdo_pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite.so' (tried: ext/pdo_sqlite.so (ext/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo_sqlite.so.so (ext/pdo_sqlite.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql.so' (tried: ext/pgsql.so (ext/pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pgsql.so.so (ext/pgsql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'phar.so' (tried: ext/phar.so (ext/phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/phar.so.so (ext/phar.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'posix.so' (tried: ext/posix.so (ext/posix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/posix.so.so (ext/posix.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pspell.so' (tried: ext/pspell.so (ext/pspell.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pspell.so.so (ext/pspell.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'readline.so' (tried: ext/readline.so (ext/readline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/readline.so.so (ext/readline.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'recode.so' (tried: ext/recode.so (ext/recode.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/recode.so.so (ext/recode.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'shmop.so' (tried: ext/shmop.so (ext/shmop.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/shmop.so.so (ext/shmop.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'simplexml.so' (tried: ext/simplexml.so (ext/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/simplexml.so.so (ext/simplexml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'snmp.so' (tried: ext/snmp.so (ext/snmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/snmp.so.so (ext/snmp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'soap.so' (tried: ext/soap.so (ext/soap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/soap.so.so (ext/soap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets.so' (tried: ext/sockets.so (ext/sockets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sockets.so.so (ext/sockets.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3.so' (tried: ext/sqlite3.so (ext/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sqlite3.so.so (ext/sqlite3.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvmsg.so' (tried: ext/sysvmsg.so (ext/sysvmsg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sysvmsg.so.so (ext/sysvmsg.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvsem.so' (tried: ext/sysvsem.so (ext/sysvsem.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sysvsem.so.so (ext/sysvsem.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvshm.so' (tried: ext/sysvshm.so (ext/sysvshm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sysvshm.so.so (ext/sysvshm.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tidy.so' (tried: ext/tidy.so (ext/tidy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/tidy.so.so (ext/tidy.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tokenizer.so' (tried: ext/tokenizer.so (ext/tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/tokenizer.so.so (ext/tokenizer.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: ext/wddx.so (ext/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/wddx.so.so (ext/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlreader.so' (tried: ext/xmlreader.so (ext/xmlreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xmlreader.so.so (ext/xmlreader.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlrpc.so' (tried: ext/xmlrpc.so (ext/xmlrpc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xmlrpc.so.so (ext/xmlrpc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlwriter.so' (tried: ext/xmlwriter.so (ext/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xmlwriter.so.so (ext/xmlwriter.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: ext/xsl.so (ext/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xsl.so.so (ext/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: ext/zip.so (ext/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/zip.so.so (ext/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: ext/memcached.so (ext/memcached.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/memcached.so.so (ext/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.23-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct  8 2019 05:31:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
ronak@ronak-pc ~ $
```

I am using linux mint 18.3

in my system magento is already running. phpmyadmin is also running. I did not get what is problem. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your php instance on server missed few extensions (and it still try to load them, suggesting these extensions were still present in additional php configs (so first try to check these additional configs within /etc/php subdirs and comment them out (exact ones, which drops errors currently) and after simpy reinstall them with package manager command (yum upgrade php-opcache, f.e. - for centos or for debian/ubuntu - apt reinstall php-opcache and same for all toher modules, which were mentioned earlier

Comment: Ok let me try it..